# Why the unsigned application does not find the Application class?

Tags: android

The application that I am developing is crashing in some mobiles when it is not signed. When I sign the application, it works perfectly on the same devices that previously made the application crashes.

The error is:

```
Process: com.my.application, PID: 10293 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.my.application.di.base.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my.application.di.base.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.application-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.application-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4526)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my.application.di.base.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.application-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.application-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:980)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
... 10 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.application.di.base.App
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I'm not obfuscating my code, nor use instant run. I'm using multidex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating debug apk create it from Build>Build APK. The issue you are facing is because of instant run.

Comment: I'm not using instant run.

Comment: Have you tried creating apk from build menu ->build apk

Comment: You're right. Although I do not use instant run in Android Studio, the apk that generates when I release the version to a mobile and that apk I install it in another mobile is when it forces the closing. When I give Build -> Build APK, Android Studio generates the correct apk. We can see that the weights of the apk in one and in the other are totally different.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use proguard or any other method to obfuscate your code?

Comment: No, I'm not obfuscating my code, nor use instant run

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: I'm using multidex